# Require Elem when using Sorbet RBI

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I want to extend the standard `Array` with a new instance method but I keep getting a runtime error about the `type_member` not being found.

The definition looks like this.

```
class Array
  extend T::Sig
  extend T::Generic

  sig do
    type_parameters(:U)
      .params(split_elem: T.type_parameter(:U))
      .returns(T::Array[Elem])
  end
  def split_on(split_elem)
    output = []
    group = []
    each do |elem|
      if elem.eql?(split_elem)
        output << group unless group.empty?
        group = []
      else
        group << elem
      end
    end
    output << group unless group.empty?
    output
  end
end
```

Is there a way to explicitly require the [rbi file](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/blob/ae981a30546c613a59abfcb7f6aecf6754b87983/rbi/core/array.rbi) declaring `Elem`?

When trying to run the code, I get the following error. I have tried requiring the `sorbet-runtime` but no success so far.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Array::Elem

      .returns(T::Array[Elem])
```

Comment: Where does `Elem` come from? Can you `require` it?

Comment: That is exactly my question. `Elem` comes from the rbi file for arrays [found here on github](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/blob/ae981a30546c613a59abfcb7f6aecf6754b87983/rbi/core/array.rbi)
but I have not been able to find a way to require it.

Comment: @engineersmnky It seems some of the text from your comment was lost. I assume you mean something like `arr.chunk` together with a `map()` as in `a.chunk { |n| !n.eql?(0) || nil }.map(&:last)` for splittling a list of integers on zero? If so, yes this is just a more readable version of that.

But the main question is about extending classes from the core api using `T::Generic` and `type_member`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RBI files are purely static artifacts, they are not meant to be required or run in any way. So, the high-level answer to your question is "no, you can't require RBI files".

The problem you are facing is that you are adding a signature that is statically checkable (i.e. Sorbet can understand `Elem` and type-check your code without running it), but it is not valid at runtime, since there is no actual `Elem` constant under the Ruby `Array` class.

There are three ways you can square this circle:

1. You want to actually return the same type of the receiver, in which case, you can just use `T.self_type` as the return type, which will solve your problem with `Elem`. Docs for `T.self_type` are [here](https://sorbet.org/docs/self-type).
2. You can move the inline signature for `Array#split_on` to an RBI file, which will make the signature checked only statically (based on what I said about RBI files above), or
3. You can use `T::Sig::WithoutRuntime.sig` instead of `sig` to write your signature, as explained [here](https://sorbet.org/docs/runtime#tsigwithoutruntimesig).

Comment: Thank you! For other people coming here, also check out https://sorbet.org/docs/self-type which was pointed out by @paracycle in another channel.

Comment: @fre Updated the answer to include that information as well.