# uninitialized constant Array::Elem

Tags: ruby, sorbet

The following recommended solution from [the Sorbet FAQ](https://sorbet.org/docs/faq#sigs-are-vague-for-stdlib-methods-that-accept-keyword-arguments--have-multiple-return-types) results in `uninitialized constant Array::Elem` during execution (`bundle exec srb tc` runs fine):

```
# typed: true

class Array
  extend T::Sig

  sig { returns(Elem) } # or T.nilable(Elem) unless you're confident this is never called on empty arrays
  def sample_one
    T.cast(sample, Elem)
  end

  sig { params(n: Integer).returns(T::Array[Elem]) }
  def sample_n(n)
    T.cast(sample(n), T::Array[Elem])
  end
end
```

I added this class to config/initializers/monkeypatches/array.rb in a Rails project.

I'm aware of [Require Elem when using Sorbet RBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74842702/require-elem-when-using-sorbet-rbi), but since the above solution is from the official Sorbet FAQ, I'm hoping there actually is a way to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

The FAQ says that the above type is what to write in an RBI file, not a Ruby source file.

The Ruby VM does not define stdlib classes as Sorbet generics—you will have to use T::Sig::WithoutRuntime if you wish to monkey patch Array:

https://sorbet.org/docs/runtime#tsigwithoutruntimesig

Comment: Before the example (below the RBI examples), it states "Another alternative is to define new methods that are stricter about arguments, and use these in place of stdlib methods", and it includes implementation of the methods (the code in my original post). I don't understand how implementation can be part of an RBI file.